# Unable to import 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium

I think I have a very simple problem that I just don't know how to solve. Even though I installed selenium AND chromedriver with the appropriate version for my browser, I get an error message on VSCode saying "Unable to import 'selenium'. This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```

When I hit "Save All" There's a red line and the error above. Pls I need some help here.

Comment: You might have multiple versions of Python on your machine and installed selenium in one of them and try to run the code with an other version.

Comment: Yeah I just had two versions installed. by uninstalling both and then reinstalling one it got solved. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the code with another version of python, or trying to install selenium module using pip:

```
pip install selenium
```

or

```
pip3 install selenium
```

if not work

```
python3 -m pip3 install selenium / python -m pip3 install selenium / python -m pip install selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should try to install the Selenium with the pip package manager.

But please follow the next steps.

```
1- Open a cmd window
2- write only the next script:
"pip install selenium --user"
```

you might need some user permissions, that´s why you should use "--user" after the "pip install selenium", then close the cmd window after running the script in it, then reset the computer, and that should be enough. let me know if it worked.